# Why won't my WiFi work with a Belkin USB dongle and WPA2?

Tags: 11.04, networking, wireless

I am using a Belkin usb dongle to connect to my wifi  network with a wpa2 key. Most of the times Ubuntu is not able to connect to the network automatically and keeps on asking for the key, even though the correct key has already been entered.

It connects after restarting networking multiple times.

I am on 11.04 with the latest updates.

Answer (score 1):

Try using wicd instead of native network-manager. I had similar issues, mostly related to bizarre unexpected wifi disconnections - after upgrading to 11.04. I never had this problem on earlier versions of ubuntu to be honest.

Answer (score -1):

I once had to use an Acer Aspire TimelineX that had an unsupported wireless card. I downloaded wicd via wired and it worked perfectly, although it doesn't show up in your panel.